# Understanding higher-order function type declaration

Tags: haskell, type-declaration

In the introductory Haskell text, *Learn You a Haskell for Great Good*, the author defines a function, applyTwice, that two times applies a function f to a parameter x to illustrate the higher order capabilities central to the functional paradigm.

```
applyTwice :: (a -> a) -> a -> a  
applyTwice f x = f (f x)
```

To this point, I found Haskell's type declarations clear, but this particular example confuses me. I think this is an opportunity to better understand type declarations.

The author indicates this construct "indicates that the first parameter is a function that takes something and returns that same thing. The second parameter is something of that type also and the return value is also of the same type." ([text](http://learnyouahaskell.com/higher-order-functions#higher-orderism))

**What does this type declaration mean?** Why not use (a -> a) -> a, with each -> indicating a transformation of some sort?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In between each `->` is the type of a parameter to the function, with the last one being the type of the function's return value. So here the shape is `_ -> _ -> _` (a function taking two parameters). The first parameter, though, happens to be a function, and has shape `_ -> _` (taking one parameter).

So to use `applyTwice`:

- pass a function that when given an `a` will return an `a`
- pass an `a`
- get an `a` as the result

Comment: Or, equivalently, pass a function that when given an `a` will return an `a`, and get as a result a function that when given an `a` will return an `a`.

Answer (score 2):

You should thing `a -> b` as a function that takes a `a` and outputs a `b` - so if `f` is such a function: `f :: a -> b` then everytime you feed it an `v :: a` (written as `f v`) you get an `b`: `(f v) :: b`.

Now of course such a function-type is a *type* too - *higher order ...* ;)

Now `(a -> a) -> a -> a` is `(a -> a) -> (a -> a)` so this is a *function* (let's call it `applyTwice`) that when given an `f :: a -> a` will produce another function `a -> a`: `applyTwice f :: a -> a` which is of course the function that take an `v :: a` and then does `f (f a)` (*applying `f` twice*).

If you have `(a -> a) -> a` on the other hand you have to somehow produce an `a` from a function of type `a -> a` which is really tricky (think about it: where do you get an `a` from that you can feed `f`?